# redirect from page b.html if page a.html isnt visited first

Tags: redirect

how to redirect someone from page `B.html` if before they haven't visited page `A.html`.

If page `A.html` is visited then allow to open and `B.html`.

All pages are html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a cookie when the visitor goes to a.html. When the visitor navigates to b.html check to see if the cookie has been set, if not, initiate a redirect.

All this can be achieved using Javascript/jQuery / HTML.

jQuery cookie library: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Redirecting in JavaScript: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

### Code

Include jQuery and the jQuery cookie plugin on both a.html and b.html. Make sure you download a copy of the jquery.cookie.js file from the github repo linked above.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

On page a.html use this snippet of code to set the cookie when your visitor loads the page:

```
<script>
    $.cookie('page_a_visited', 'true', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
</script>
```

On page b.html add this code snippet to check if the vistor has the cookie set, and if not, redirect them back to page a.html:

```
<script>
    if($.cookie('page_a_visited') !='true') {
        window.location.replace("/a.html");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please can you give some simple writen exaple.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer above. Question is how to make this cookie valid only on sessio, until browser is closed?

Comment: Just remove the {expires:7,} part of the options when setting the cookie.